# how can i authenticate this form with firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i created this UI but i cant seem to place in the right fields to authenticate it. Here is my code
do i need to switch up my whole code before doing it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import  'Logins/checkboxes.dart';


class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => new _SignUpState();
}


class _SignUpState extends State <SignUp> {




 TextStyle style = TextStyle (fontFamily: '', fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black);


  
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

i tried to put Form() here but it keeps bringing up an error that says it needs child first
and final does not support the children widget so how do i go about it?

```
    final firstnameField = TextFormField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        hintText: "Firstname",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
        icon: Icon(Icons.contacts)
      ),
    );


    final lasttnameField = TextFormField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        hintText: "Lastname",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
        icon: Icon(Icons.contacts)
      ),
    );


    final emailField = TextFormField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        hintText: "Email",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
        icon: Icon(Icons.mail)
      ),
    
    );


     final passwordField = TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        hintText: "Password",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
         icon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key)
      ),
    
    );



    final registerButton = Material(

      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> CheckBoxInListview())
          );
        },
        child: Text("Proceed", textAlign:TextAlign.center , style: style.copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), // text
      ),

    );


    return Scaffold(
      
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

   // backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
      body:new Stack(
      
      
    

        children: <Widget>[


          Center(
            
            child: Container(
              //color: Colors.blue[200],
              decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/images/Artboardd.png"), fit:BoxFit.cover,),),
              child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),  
              child: Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox( height: 15.0,),
                Text("Register", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Pacifico', fontSize:50.0),),
                
                SizedBox( height: 45.0),

                firstnameField,

                SizedBox(height: 25.0),

                lasttnameField,

                SizedBox(height: 25.0),

                emailField,

                SizedBox( height: 25.0),

                passwordField,

                SizedBox( height: 25.0),

                registerButton,
                SizedBox( height: 15.0),

               
              ]
              
),
             
              ),
             
            ),
          )
      

        ],

        
      ),

    );


  
    
  }


  

}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation .Also there are many tutorials out there showing how to authenticate a user using firebase. There are plenty of tutorials showing how to authenticate that user through email and password and sign in with google. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap all the form widgets inside the ***form widget*** and after that, you can add validation to the form and once the form is validated you can simply use FirebaseAuth's API to register the user using email and password.

Form Validation

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                // otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) async{
                  // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                     await handleSignUp(email,password);
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

SignIn and SignUp

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignInEmail(String email, String password) async {

    AuthResult result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    final FirebaseUser user = result.user;

    assert(user != null);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    print('signInEmail succeeded: $user');

    return user;

  }

Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignUp(email, password) async {

    AuthResult result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    final FirebaseUser user = result.user;

    assert (user != null);
    assert (await user.getIdToken() != null);

    return user;

  }
```